# Math in programming: Trigonmetry about rotating angle between points

Tags: android, math, trigonometry, angle

I have a problem of finding the angle of three points with mouse pointer. The rotation doesn't following the mouse as the mouse move around the rotating object.

This is my formula :

```
double degree = Math.toDegrees( Math.atan2(
                 (now.y - point.y) - (previous.y - point.y),
                 (now.x - point.x) - (previous.x - point.x)));

         Log.w("RESULT", "DEGREE = " + degree);
        if ( degree < 0 )
          degree = 360 - (-degree);
```

This last 2 line was added later.

This is the full code of tracking the mouse rotation.

Camera camera = Camera.getInstance();

```
     if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
         event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
         previous = new Point(event.getX(), event.getY());
         previous = camera.getMapPoint(previous);

     }
     else if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && 
         event.getPointerCount() == 1) 
     {  
         Point now = new Point(event.getX(), event.getY());
         now = camera.getMapPoint(now);

         ArrayList<GameObject> list = mObject.getSubObjects();
         GameObject part = list.get(0);
         Point point = part.getPolygon().getCenter();

         Log.w("RESULT", "Previous = " + previous.x + " " + previous.y);
         Log.w("RESULT", "Next = " + now.x + " " + now.y);
         Log.w("RESULT", "Center = " + point.x + " " + now.y);

         double degree = Math.toDegrees( Math.atan2(
                 (now.y - point.y) - (previous.y - point.y),
                 (now.x - point.x) - (previous.x - point.x)));

         Log.w("RESULT", "DEGREE = " + degree);
        if ( degree < 0 )
          degree = 360 - (-degree);


         android.graphics.Matrix matrix = new android.graphics.Matrix();
         matrix.postRotate((float) degree, point.x, point.y);


        // Polygon polygon;
        // Polygon.Builder builder = new Polygon.Builder();
         for (int i=0; i<part.getPolygon().getVertex().size(); i++) 
         {
             float[] newPoint = new float[2];
             Point p = part.getPolygon().getVertex().get(i);
             newPoint[0] = p.x;
             newPoint[1] = p.y;

             matrix.mapPoints(newPoint); 
             part.getPolygon().getVertex().remove(i);
             part.getPolygon().getVertex().add(i, new Point(newPoint[0], newPoint[1]));

         } 
         previous = new Point(event.getX(), event.getY());
         previous = camera.getMapPoint(previous);
     }
     else if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
     {
        previous = null; 
        isSelected = false;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find angle between vectors (point-previous) and (point-now), use:

```
 Math.atan2((now.x - point.x)*(previous.y - point.y) - 
           (now.y - point.y)*(previous.x - point.x), 
           (now.x - point.x)*(now.y - point.y) - 
           (previous.x - point.x)*(previous.y - point.y))
```

(This is `atan2(vectorproduct, scalarproduct)`)

You may also use

```
angle = atan2(now.y-point.y, now.y-point.y)-
        atan2(previous.y-point.y, previous.x-point.x);
```

Comment: Thank you .... do you know where i can find the information for this. It work but looks like it goes in different directions

Comment: It finds angle needed to rotate (point-now) vector to be collinear with (point-previous). You can change sign of the first expression (vector product) to invert rotation.

Comment: Although, the rotation work but it doesn't follow the same speed as my finger when rotating. It does rotate and follow my finger if my finger goes slowly but any slightly speeding up the rotation couldn't catch-up